# What are AI characters doing when not in the viewport?

Tags: ai

In a game like star wars battlefront, 100+ AI characters are competing against each other both onscreen and offscreen to shoot each other and capture bases. My question is what types of efficient techniques may be used to handle the processing of this activity for the characters not in the viewport?

Obviously, the actual game objects/meshes can't be moving around. Is there a global game AI that selects characters and then actions, then records them, and then places the game objects only when they get into the viewport? Or is it decentralized and each game object knows it's own position/goals but just becomes visible/hidden by a global manager based on the viewport? Any other tricks I'm not thinking about?

Edit: My military sim game has similar functionality. Multiple factions are fighting, dying, and occupying land. Terrain is all land but has caves and rudimentary buildings.

Comment: We can't necessarily tell you how Star Wars Battlefront does it, but we can help you design an appropriate method *for your game* if you're considering adding a feature like this. Just edit your question to give us some details about how your game works and what kinds of things the AI need to do.

Comment: We had a solution somewhat similar to what you describe on Starlink Battle for Atlas: Legion robots multiply and ravage planets even when you're not there, and friendly factions fight against them. In our case we had a simplified "SimUnit" for each logical group of characters, that would navigate a simplified graph representing the planet. A background thread would iterate over the SimUnits and update their states periodically. When you got close enough, we'd "realize" the SimUnit into the actual 3D characters you see, and hand off to their full AI behaviour.

Comment: @DMGregory I see, a simplified graph that a global manager moves units through "on paper" until they are in view. I imagine that when units get close they can fight with each other "on paper" as well. I updated my question as well

Comment: 100+ AI characters can be no problem (e.g. in real time strategy games), or can be huge mess. What is your bottleneck? It is common for AI to go into a less functional state when it is away from the player, however exactly how changes from game to game. For instance, path finding can be the bottle neck… But crowds can use influence maps for path finding, AI agents out of view (or waiting for their turn to use path finding) may resource to more simplistic algorithms but cheaper algorithms such as crash and turn. Or agents may not exist far from view and you just simulate influence maps moving.

Comment: I want to recommend the channel [Ai and Games](https://www.youtube.com/c/AIGamesSeries/) there are many videos that might be relevant. You might be interested in the videos on Total War, Command & Conquer, Hitman, Halo, Horizon Zero Dawn, and Hyrule Warriors. They all have interesting approaches to having a large number of AI controlled characters. By the way, some games will spawn units as a visual representation of the state of a system, only when you are looking. Such would be the case of city building games.